# Write Methods and Unit Tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing

At the moment I'm programming some Unit Tests in C# for my WebService. So the read methods all easy to do but now I want to test my write functions.

When I start my tests for the write methods I always get a new database entry. Is there a way to run the test function get the result and after that the test function do a rollback so the new entry is no longer in the db?

Or how do you test write functions?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I start a transaction at the beginning of the test and then roll it back.

Implementation-wise, this should be easy to do by wrapping your test code in a `TransactionScope` and not `Complete`-ing it. (Add a comment, so that your co-workers don't assume you just forgot it.)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you have back-end code that simulates writing to a DB i.e. using a mocking framework see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19674363/when-to-use-a-mocking-framework/) link - in short, your nunit tests shouldn't be doing any DB / web service calls so they can run quickly and reliably.